# How can I speed up query execution that compares substrings

Tags: sql, firebird, database-performance

I am using Firebird, little I know of Firebird. I have a query and I want to speed it up because it is taking 17s. The line that causing trouble is this:

```
 left join table1 t1 on substring(t1.column1 from 1 for 8) = substring(t2.column2 from 1 for 8)
```

it is comparing the first 8 characters of a varying char column. When I perform like this

```
 left join table1 t1 t1.column1 = t2.column2
```

It takes only 5s. That's exactly what I want.

I cannot remodel the database. It was not me that built it.

Comment: If you have to use substring it is a sign that your database is not normalized enough. Consider extraction of these 8 characters into a separate field.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, your only hope for such a query is an index on the expression.  Firebird supports indexes on expressions, so try:

```
create index idx_table1_col1_8 on table1
    computed by (substring(column1 from 1 for 8));
```

I don't think an index on `table2` is actually needed for the query.

Comment: It doesn't let me use substring at index creation

Comment: @DiegoAlves . . . You may be using a very old version of Firebird.  More likely, though, the expression needs parentheses, which I added into the question.

Comment: More likely is old Firebird version.

Comment: @DiegoAlves expression indexes were introduced in Firebird 2.0, and the statement as shown now (I corrected a minor issue) works fine in Firebird 2.0. If you're still using Firebird 1.5, then you really should consider upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options. As Gordon suggests, you can create a computed index, but you can also use a normal index on `column1` of `table1`, and change your condition to a prefix search: `on t1.column1 starting with substring(t2.column2 from 1 for 8)`. If present [`STARTING WITH`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-commons-predstartwith) will use the index.

This solution only works if you always need the prefix of `column1` to match (i.e. in terms of your original solution: always `from 1` in the substring on `column1` of `table1`).